Car acts like battery is dead but then starts
My daughter is away at college. She called me the other day and said her car wouldn't lock with the fob or the button inside. Then when she tried to start it it wouldn't start. Acted like battery was dead. She tried 2 more times.  And then it randomly started. What could it be? Checked battery at autozone. They said it was good.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Did they check the battery in the key fob?
